# Jquery Countup Until Next Monday and total Mondays from defined date until todays date

Tags: jquery, count, counter

I'm trying to code a count up that show how many MONDAYS we had from a specific date.

For example since 10/01/2012 we had 4 mondays until today October 25.

This first step I could achieve with some coding searching from some places and adapting it to my needs.

Now the tricky part for me is to make a way to show a count up that shows a percentage of how much from now to the next month is remaining to increase another monday to the main counter.

For example, from 10/01/2012 we had 4 mondays until now, but October 25 is Thursday so how could I do a count up that shows the time increasing with the value that is remaining to achieve next monday?

I tried to put as a count up like using days, hours, minutes and seconds so everytime it runs it starts from today  with the value counting up to the next monday so week by week we would have a number like this in the counter: 6days 23hours 59minutes 59seconds and then add a new number to the number of mondays so we achieved a new monday after the 6 days, but of course if I visit the page running the code in the middle I will already have the counter with the value added on it and counting each second live.

Could someone help? If you know a better way to achieve the same goal it is perfectly ok.

**To summarize what I want to achieve is a counter that says how many mondays have passed and how much time is left to the next monday and counting up live. It has to keep going for ever not to stop on the next monday, after achieving the following monday it keeps going until the next.**

Questions are welcome!

```
<pre><code>


// This Code Counts how many mondays from a specified date to the actual date.
// Create a new date variable
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getDate();

// Get the actual date and store on a variable
var actualDate = d.getFullYear() + '/' + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' + (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;

// Set dates start and get actual date
var date1 = new Date('10/01/2012'); // Set the begninning date here
var date2 = new Date(actualDate);

var monday = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
monday -= 0.1;
monday = Math.floor(monday);
monday *= 1;

if (date1.getDay() == 1) monday += 1;
if (date2.getDay() == 1) monday += 1;

//$('').html(monday);
$("#showMondays").text(monday);

</pre></code>
```

This is the working monday counter: http://jsfiddle.net/hRaAF/

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that what you are actually trying to achieve is a count *down* to the next monday?

Comment: it's actually the opposite, should be a count UP.  from the date X until today we had 4 mondays for example, I would like to show from the time users are on the website how much has been since the last monday already and how far we are from the next one. so if we are in the middle of the week we should show half of the value (time like days hours minutes seconds) on the count up and show it increasing in order to complete another monday when we get there... it's like how much of percentage we still need to complete to get another monday added to the counter....

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to your fiddle, you can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hRaAF/24/).

```
var nextMonday = function(now) {
    var day = now.getUTCDay();
    var next = new Date();
    next.setDate(next.getDate() + (7 - day));
    next.setHours(0);
    next.setMinutes(0);
    next.setSeconds(0);
    return next;
};

var SECS = 1000;
var MINS = 60 * SECS;
var HOURS = 60 * MINS;
var DAYS = 24 * HOURS;

var countDown = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var next = nextMonday(now);
    var difference = Math.abs(next - now);

    var days = Math.floor(difference / DAYS);
    difference = difference % DAYS;
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / HOURS);
    difference = difference % HOURS;
    var minutes = Math.floor(difference / MINS);
    difference = difference % MINS;
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / SECS);

    var text = days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds ';

    $('#count').text(text);
    setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
};

countDown();
setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
```

---

**EDIT**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hRaAF/38/)'s the modified code. I removed the previous code that calculated the number of mondays since a given monday and replaced with a simpler version. You can test it changing the date and time in your computer since that's where javascript gets the values for the current date.

```
var begin = new Date('10/01/2012');

var SECS = 1000;
var MINS = 60 * SECS;
var HOURS = 60 * MINS;
var DAYS = 24 * HOURS;
var WEEKS = 7 * DAYS;

var countMondaysFrom = function(begin) {
    var difference = Math.abs(new Date() - begin);
    var days = Math.floor(difference / WEEKS);
    return days;

};

var lastMonday = function(now) {
    var day = now.getUTCDay() - 1;
    day = day < 0 ? 6 : day;
    var last = new Date();
    last.setDate(last.getDate() - day);
    last.setHours(0);
    last.setMinutes(0);
    last.setSeconds(0);
    return last;
};

var countUp = function() {
    var now = new Date();
    var last = lastMonday(now);
    var difference = Math.abs(now - last);

    var days = Math.floor(difference / DAYS);
    difference = difference % DAYS;
    var hours = Math.floor(difference / HOURS);
    difference = difference % HOURS;
    var minutes = Math.floor(difference / MINS);
    difference = difference % MINS;
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / SECS);

    var text = days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' minutes ' + seconds + ' seconds ';

    $('#count').text(text);
    $("#showMondays").text(countMondaysFrom(begin));
    setTimeout(countUp, 1000);
};

countUp();
setTimeout(countUp, 1000);​
```

Comment: juan I think it works but for some reason it seems to have some problem with the days, when I opened it shows 5 days but today is sunday, but if I do not consider the amount of days and just get the hours remaining to the next monday it works. would it be possible to make the opposite, instead of counting down we add up seconds, minutes, hours and days until the next monday, so every time we have  the counter reaching a new monday it increases the value of the mondays counter and reset the count up to keep going...